# How does $\sum_s\left[u_a^s(p)\bar u_b^s(p) + v_a^s(-p)\bar v_b^s(-p)\right] = 2E_p\gamma^0_{ab}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

For Dirac spinors, we have the spin sums for particles,
$$
\sum_{s=1,2}u_a^s(p)\bar u_b^s(p) = (\not\!p+m)_{ab},
$$
and for antiparticles:
$$
\sum_{s=1,2}v_a^s(p)\bar v_b^s(p) = (\not\!p-m)_{ab}.
$$
As $\{u^s(p),v^s(-p)\}$ span the spinor space, and are normalized to $2E_p$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\sum_s\left[u_a^s(p)\bar u_b^s(p) + v_a^s(-p)\bar v_b^s(-p)\right] = 2E_p\gamma^0
\end{equation*}
I'm struggling with verifying this relationship. If we sum over the two spin sums for particles and antiparticles, shouldn't we get $2\!\not\!p_{ab} = 2(\gamma^0p_0-\gamma^i p_i)$? It seems like the third equality contains $2\gamma^0p_0$ only.

Comment: Based on your first two equations, it looks like the sum in the third equation line should be zero... I.e., it looks like the RHS is $(\not p+ m) + (-\not p - m) = m-m = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct relation involves inverting only the three-momentum of the spinors,
$$\sum_{s}\left[u^{s}(\mathbf{p})\bar{u}^{s}(\mathbf{p}) + v^{s}(-\mathbf{p})\bar{v}^{s}(-\mathbf{p})\right] = 2E_p\gamma^{0}.$$
This follows straightforwardly from the closure relations, which may be written
$$\sum_{s}u^{s}(\mathbf{p})\bar{u}^{s}(\mathbf{p})=E_{\mathbf{p}}\gamma^{0}-\pmb{\gamma}\cdot\mathbf{p}+m \\
\sum_{s}v^{s}(\mathbf{-p})\bar{v}^{s}(\mathbf{-p})=E_{\mathbf{p}}\gamma^{0}+\pmb{\gamma}\cdot\mathbf{p}-m,$$
which obviously sum to the required expression.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense :)